# Call ijconsole failed

Tags: j

when I installed J804 in mac, everything is ok,I use spacemacs, installed j-mode,open a j file,and use C-c C-c, it says "searching for program:no such file or directory:ijconsole. so I find /Applications/j64-806/bin, no ijconsole command, where is it?Where could I find it and  run j-file in spacemacs?

Answer (score 3):

I solve the problem
the document of j-mode says:
NB. Java on many Linux systems provides an executable which is sadly named jconsole. This means that there is a good chance j-mode will attempt to start the Java console up instead of the J console when beginning a new REPL session. The easiest fix for this, as I doubt that we can convince the Java packagers to rename their executable, is to set the j-console-cmd variable provided by j-console.el. This can be done either directly or via the custom-set-variables block.

ooh,that's the problem!

open .emacd.d/elpa/j-mode directory, in j-console.el,i find the definition of ijconsole:
(defcustom j-console-cmd "ijconsole"
  "Name of the executable used for the J REPL session"
  :type 'string
  :group 'j-console)

so it use command ijconsole to call jconsole, do follow 2steps:
1.add path Applications/j.../bin to your path
2.make a copy of jconsole and renamed it to ijconsole

Then everything is ok.